# Replace "." with "_" except for extension with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, rename, file-rename

I found the following code:

```
Dim sName
Dim fso
Dim fol

'create the filesystem object
Set fso = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'get current folder
Set fol = fso.GetFolder(".")

'go thru each file in the folder
For Each fil In fol.Files
    'check if the file name contains dot
    If InStr(1, fil.Name, ".") <> 0 Then
        'replace dot with underscore
        sName = Replace(fil.Name, ".", "_")
        'rename the file
        fil.Name = sName
    End If
Next
'echo the job is completed
WScript.Echo "Completed!"
```

However, running this .vbs file changes the extension ".", too.

e.g. I want to rename file.a.1.pdf to file_1_a.pdf but instead it renames to file_1_a_pdf.

Is there a tweak I can make to my code that will make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace dots in just the basename of the file, not the entire name, then add back the extension and rename.

```
sName = Replace(fso.GetBaseName(fil.Name), ".", "_")
fil.Name = sName & "." & fso.GetExtensionName(fil.Name)
```